# Concatenate two dataframes and remove duplicate rows based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

`df1`:

```
    Name Symbol         ID
0    Jay    N/A    372Y105
1    Ray    N/A    4446100
2   Faye    N/A    484MAA4
3   Maye    N/A    504W308
4    Kay    N/A    782L107
5   Trey    FFF    782L111
```

`df2`:

```
    Name Symbol         ID
0    Jay    AAA    372Y105
1   Faye    CCC    484MAA4
2    Kay    EEE    782L107
```

If `ID` matches between `df1` and `df2`, I want to replace the `symbol` in `df1` with the `symbol` from `df2`, so that the output looks like:

```
    Name Symbol         ID
0    Jay    AAA    372Y105
1    Ray    N/A    4446100
2   Faye    CCC    484MAA4
3   Maye    N/A    504W308
4    Kay    EEE    782L107
5   Trey    FFF    782L111
```

It sounds like I should first concatenate the two dataframes, and then drop duplicates somehow, e.g.,

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep='last')
```

But rather than only keep the first or last duplicate, I only want to remove the ones where `symbol` = `N/A`.

Comment: In first DataFrame are only `NaN`s for `Symbol` column? Then use `df = df1.drop('Symbol', axis=1).merge(df2, on=['Name','ID'], how='left')`

Comment: No first Dataframe can have values other than `N/A` too. I've updated the original to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with left join first and then replace missing values in `Symbol` column by `Symbol_` column:

```
print (df1.merge(df2, on=['Name','ID'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_')))
   Name Symbol       ID Symbol_
0   Jay    NaN  372Y105     AAA
1   Ray    NaN  4446100     NaN
2  Faye    NaN  484MAA4     CCC
3  Maye    NaN  504W308     NaN
4   Kay    NaN  782L107     EEE
5  Trey    FFF  782L111     NaN

df = (df1.merge(df2, on=['Name','ID'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_'))
         .assign(Symbol = lambda x: x['Symbol'].fillna(x.pop('Symbol_'))))
print (df)
   Name Symbol       ID
0   Jay    AAA  372Y105
1   Ray    NaN  4446100
2  Faye    CCC  484MAA4
3  Maye    NaN  504W308
4   Kay    EEE  782L107
5  Trey    FFF  782L111
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['Name','ID'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['Name','ID'])
df1.update(df2)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   Name       ID Symbol
0   Jay  372Y105    AAA
1   Ray  4446100    NaN
2  Faye  484MAA4    CCC
3  Maye  504W308    NaN
4   Kay  782L107    EEE
5  Trey  782L111    FFF
```

Comment: When I do this on my full dataset it just returns `df1`. Only difference are the column names.

Comment: @MSD - Added output after `merge` and also another solution, can you check it?